# Using two different versions of the same DLL in an ASP site using two SDK's

Tags: c#, asp.net, sdk

I am trying to use an application called DynamicDashboards to create a stats dashboard at work. This is precompiled using two other dependencies Ext.Net 1.5.0.0 and Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.8.0. At the same time I am trying to use a newer version of Ext.Net 2.1 to build some modules which requires Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.0.0.

Since in both cases the DLL's have the same name and most of the same types I am getting errors about types being available in both DLL's and/or the wrong version is loaded.

How can I use DynamicDashboards with Ext.Net 2.1 and resolve the conflicts?
I do not have the source for DynamicDashboards, I do have the source for Ext.Net and Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: This is partially covered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445188/using-two-dlls-with-same-name-and-same-namespace - it's not trivial, really. However, if the DLL's are strongly named, I'd imagine you might be able to get away with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference both assemblies. Select each on in the Solution Explorer and look at the properties. There should be an `Aliases` property. Usually this is set to `global`, however you can change and/or add to this. For example call the first reference `Lib1` and the second `Lib2`.

In your C# you must then put an extern to it, such as:

```
extern alias Lib1;
```

You can then reference each individual assembly, like this:

```
Lib1::Some.Namespace.Type
Lib2::Some.Namespace.Type
```

If you'd like a better explaination of this read this blog post - http://www.lloydkinsella.net/2012/07/13/extern-alias-underused-or-unknown/

Comment: how can I do this on a precompiled dll that uses it as a dependency?

Comment: AFAIK you can't do it on a precompiled library, there's no way of telling it to use one namespace over another, that's done at compile time :/