# 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' exists in both

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sqlite

I have two usercontrols with nuget Package sqlite and can just add one reference to a Mainprogram
if I add the second reference I got this error:

```
Error   10  The type 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' exists in both 'c:\Work\- Samples\- Wpf\testwrap\MediaViewerControl\bin\Debug\MediaViewerControl.dll' 
        and 'c:\Work\ItuneLibUtility-12\DiscOgsSearchCtrl\DiscOgsSearchCtrl\bin\Debug\DiscOgsSearchCtrl.dll'    
        C:\Work\ItuneLibUtility-12\MDreamMediaViewer\MDreamMediaViewer\Dialogs\MovieDialog2.xaml.cs
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Look into `extern alias`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445188/using-two-dlls-with-same-name-and-same-namespace or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx

Comment: The Tip was good I give the Second Reference an alias (in the reference settings in Visual Studio) thanks. A good refence was also http://www.davidarno.org/c-howtos/aliases-overcoming-name-conflicts-part-2-extern-alias/  here.