# Same assembly name issue

Tags: asp.net, .net-assembly, facebook-c#-sdk

I have two dll called Facebook with different definition. I am using both dll in my project. But the problem is I am unable add reference the two dll since both have the same name. Since its a third party dll I can't changed the name of assembly.How to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you GAC install it and then define it using the fully qualified name?

Comment: Have a look  [Using two DLLs with same name and same namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445188/using-two-dlls-with-same-name-and-same-namespace)