# Referencing dll of different versions in same application or redirecting to new version

Tags: c#, .net, excel

can we reference dll of different versions in same application...Actullay currently some uses DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll is of version 2.0.5022.0,but I want to use the higer version 2.6.0.0 of it..
It  throws exception for the "Export to excel" function
I have tried following redirecting in web.config

```
   <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.5022.0" newVersion="2.6.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>       
  </assemblyBinding>
```

But it still throws exception in event log:
Message: Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Exception type: System.IO.FileLoadException
Stack Trace: 
at CMS.ImportExport.DataExportHelper.ExportToExcel(DataSet dataSet, Stream stream)
at CMS.ImportExport.DataExportHelper.ExportData(DataExportFormatEnum format, HttpResponse response)

I need updated version of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll i.e version 2.6.0.0 for my functionality implementation
How can I resolve it for "Export to Excel"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using two DLLs with same name and same namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445188/using-two-dlls-with-same-name-and-same-namespace)

Comment: You might find this useful https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/837908