# referencing assembly with different version in c# wpf project

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, reference, .net-assembly

I need to use different version of same assembly in my project. so i have searched option and found below mentioned stackoverflow link and followed that first  (Joel Gauvreau) answer.

[Referencing 2 different versions of log4net in the same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158928/referencing-2-differents-versions-of-log4net-in-the-same-solution)

i have done all steps as mentioned in answer i have removed dll reference.

After i build my application i'm getting below error how to resolve that?

> The type or namespace name [Name of DLL removed from references] could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Use assembly redirection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to cause the referenced assembly to use the updated version of Log4Net.

Comment: @Mitch i have done that also but it not works