# NHibernate Spatial Mapping returns Antrl error

Tags: nhibernate, spatial, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am using NHibernate 3.3. I have a case where I want to insert a calculated column which is not referenced.

My Domain Entity can be reduced to the form

```
    public class Location
    {
         public virtual IPoint GeoLocation {get;set;}
    }

    public class MappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Location>
    {
        public void Override(AutoMapping<Location> mapping)
        {
            mapping
              .Map(e => e.GeoLocation)
              .Column("GeoLocation")
              .CustomSqlType("geography")
               .CustomType<MsSql2008GeographyType>;
        }
    }
```

The table column is of type 'Geography`

However it errors out as

```
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
   at GeoAPI.GeometryServiceProvider.GetLoadableTypes(Assembly assembly)
   at GeoAPI.GeometryServiceProvider.ReflectInstance()
   at GeoAPI.GeometryServiceProvider.get_Instance()
   at NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry.set_SRID(Int32 value)
```

It says that it needs `Antrl.Runtime`, but a very old version. All the `Antrl.Runtime` nuget packages out there have a different assembly identifier.

> Could not load file or assembly 'antlr.runtime, Version=2.7.6.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1790ba318ebc5d56' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I worked on a separate project where I used map by code convention and it works without any reference to `Antrl.Runtime`.

Need help to point myself in the right direction...

Comment: Is it possible to use an assembly redirect to the newer version of Antrl? Further info here (using log4net as an example): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158928/referencing-2-differents-versions-of-log4net-in-the-same-solution/3163050#3163050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a separate sample project I tried something which worked, WHICH DID NOT WORK in the actual ASP.NET MVC project.

Definition of Class

```
public class Location : IEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }

    public virtual string LocationName { get; set; }

    public virtual IPoint GeoLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping

```
public class LocationMapping : IAutoMappingOverride<Location>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Location> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Map(x => x.LocationName).Column("Name");
        mapping.Map(x => x.GeoLocation).Column("GeoLocation")
               .CustomType<MsSql2008GeographyType>();
    }
}
```

Test

```
public class WhenSavingGeoLocation : BasePersistanceTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void Save()
        {
            this.Session
             .SaveOrUpdate(new Location { 
                   LocationName = "Category 01", 
                   GeoLocation = new Point(-72.12, 32.2323234) {  SRID = 4326 } 
            });
        }
    }
```

`NHibernate.Spatial` uses `NetTopologicalSuite` which itself is a derivative of `GeoAPI`
The GeoAPI library defines an interface `GeoAPI.Geometries` and while loading / searching the correct implementation in the current project was failing with the Antlr error in the MVC project.

It was however able to fetch the `NetTopologySuite.NtsGeometryServices` implementation in the separate sample project. The actual code in GeoAPI which searches for the implementation goes like

```
       private static IGeometryServices ReflectInstance()
        {
#if !PCL
            var a = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
            foreach (var assembly in a)
            {
                // Take a look at issue 114: http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/issues/detail?id=114
                if (assembly is System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder) continue;
                if (assembly.GetType().FullName == "System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder") continue;
                if (assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache && assembly.CodeBase == Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase) continue;

                foreach (var t in GetLoadableTypes(assembly))
                {
                    if (t.IsInterface) continue;
                    if (t.IsAbstract) continue;
                    if (t.IsNotPublic) continue;
                    if (!typeof(IGeometryServices).IsAssignableFrom(t)) continue;

                    var constuctors = t.GetConstructors();
                    foreach (var constructorInfo in constuctors)
                    {
                        if (constructorInfo.IsPublic && constructorInfo.GetParameters().Length == 0)
                            return (IGeometryServices)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                    }
                }
            }
#endif
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot use GeometryServiceProvider without an assigned IGeometryServices class");
        }
    }
```

This gets called when setting the SRID on the geometry. I am guessing that my MVC project has a reference to an assembly which makes this look for Antlr.
There were some suggestions of adding a redirect for to newer Antlr assembly. I tried that as well but the error still kept repeating.