# log4net dll version conflict

Tags: c#, dll, log4net

My c# win form application is using log4net version 1.2.10.0 and one of the external api is using log4net version 1.2.11.0 so today when I consumed that api in my application I immediately bumped into issues.

It seems that for some reason Log4net team have signed the newest version of log4net 1.2.11 with a different public key. The new key means that assembly rebinding will not be possible!

I goggled to find the solution of this problem and found that so many people are facing this issue and they suggested to download the log4net 1.2.11.0 version with old key and then use assembly redirect. But the problem is even the old key is not matching with the key of log4net dll which is being used in my application.

How can I solve this problem? Can I use GAC to but not sure how.

Comment: This could be a possible solution. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: found the solution [Referencing 2 different versions of log4net in the same solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158928/referencing-2-different-versions-of-log4net-in-the-same-solution/3163050#3163050)