# Convert iTextsharp 4.1.6 to 5.x version

Tags: itext

Currently we have implemented a project in iTextsharp version 4.1.6 in .NET for client which we are working with for last 5 years, now we are facing some bugs while converting HTML tags to PDF through HTMLWorker. So, we are planning to Buy and move it to 5.x version with XMLWorker. But problem we are facing is we have used "iTextSharp.text.Table" and some old stuff extensively in the project which is not supported in 5.x version. Is there a way to convert all the code to latest version or can we use both versions simultaneously?

Comment: `Table` and `PdfPTable` are quite different. If you don't use too many "whistles and bells" in `Table`, replacing `Table` by `PdfPTable` and `Cell` by `PdfPCell` will get you close to what you need, but don't expect the visual appearance to be identical. You'll need some manual tweaking to get the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 

But, Can we use both versions simultaneously on a server? as mentioned we have used old version extensively in the code and it would not be feasible to switch it to latest version in one go.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: All the versions prior to version 5 have package names with my name in: `com.lowagie.text.*`. Starting with version 5, I removed my name from all the package names: `com.itextpdf.text.*`. As the package names are different, it is technically no problem to use both versions next to each other.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie has the namespace in iTextSharp changed similarly? I think the OP uses that version.

Comment: Aha... No, sorry. No so changes were applied in iTextSharp (I overlooked the Sharp in your question).

Comment: Created a test environment with iText 5.5.6 in .NET but was unable to find

Comment: Sorry Kindly ignore above comment. I'm working in .net can you please provide a workaround for me to use in iTextsharp 5.5.6. Thanks

Comment: By "work around" what do you mean? A work around for side-by-side 4.x and 5.x? If so, this is a general .Net issues, see [these threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451220/loading-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly)