# Using Different Version DLL from Memory

Tags: c#, dll, appdomain, multiple-versions

I have been developing an Addon for an external application. Our previous add on uses ourdll.dll v1.0.0 and our new add on uses ourdll.dll v1.1.0

Well, when we launched the external application, first of all, the first addon is loaded (also ourdll v1.0 is loaded) and then the last addon is loaded and it uses ourdll v1.1 but i think that the system checks if the same assembly is already loaded then it does not load again and the last addon tries to use ourdll v1.0 but it causes problem. Because the new version has different functions.

Almost 2 weeks, we have been looking for a solution but no way. I tried to merge/embed dlls by using babel obfuscator and i used internalize option but no way..
And then I tried this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4452193/1276061

but it also not working
PS ourdll does not have publictoken, its null..

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Distinguishing DLLs by version number requires using the GAC.  Or a different name.

Comment: Do you want to load both dlls in the same process? If not, I think you should  check all the addons' version first, and load just the newest addons.