# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, directshow, wpf-mediakit

I have a library called DirectShowLib-2005 v2.1.0.0

> http://api.256file.com/directshowlib-2005.dll/en-download-20911.html

in my project called xyz...
it runs perfectly fine until i add WPFMediaKit library

> As a Note:   It uses DirectShowLib-2005 Internally

After adding this WPFMediaKit Library it throws an Error

> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'DirectShowLib-2005, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=67e7b740cdfc2d3f' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WPFMediaKit has build    DirectShowLib-2005 v 2.1.0.26626
You directly downloaded  DirectShowLib-2005 v 2.1.0.0
```

You probably should delete the original one you downloaded.

Comment: I cant delete the original one as one or more project depended on it for showing TV and Webcam..etc.

Comment: Use a binding redirect to force version 2.1.0.0 to use 2.1.0.26626 See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451220/loading-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly

Comment: Thank you so much both the cases work for me: 1) as you suggested using binding redirect 2) changing existing dll to 2.1.0.26626