How can two plugin assemblies reference different versions of a dependency library?
Imagine I have:

A .NET (Unity) game which supports modding (not my game, so I don't have any control on it)
It loads mods that are .NET assemblies, that can bring their dependencies (deps DLLs end up in the same folder that the mod DLL)
They use different versions of an utility dependency library, ideally published on NuGet.

Now I'm the author of that third-party utility library.
I'd like that mods can consume it without being worried of assembly version conflicts. For example, ModOne loads Utility 1.0.0 and ModTwo loads Utility 2.0.0.
The default in this case is that the most recent version of the assembly (or the first being loaded, I'm not sure) wins and one of the mods will break.
I'm seeking advice on how to solve this without being a nightmare of configuration for mod authors.
I've searched the web a lot, but there's nothing quite clear and definitive for my specific use case.
Two alternatives I'm considering:

Create a strong-named assembly dependency. Can mod authors reference it via <PackageReference>, then use <Reference> to specify the publick key token, and then use an alias to force the use of a specific version. Would that even work? I can also skip NuGet and directly provide a downloadable .dll if that helps.
Publish new versions but adding new namespaces as breaking changes occur, ex. UtilityLib.Feature.V2. It would work as long as it's always the newest assembly version that is loaded, but I don't know if it's always the case, seems dependent on the .NET runtime is use, and I don't know how the game/Unity handles this. No explicit assembly binding redirect is possible to my knowledge because we don't control the config of the game.
Publish the dependency as a mod, but for various reasons I'd like to avoid this solution.

I seek specific guidance on this problem, as similar questions but for slightly different use cases have already been answered, generally in a vague manner. Not being extremely familiar with .NET, I'm at a loss.
In conclusion: is possible at all to do that in .NET in a deterministic way that doesn't involve heavy workarounds and complicated setup for mod authors, or should I give up?
Edit
Just tried approach #1, with a random already-existing strong named assembly.
This is the configuration in one mod:
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper.StrongName" Version="1.60.1" GeneratePathProperty="true" Aliases="DapperV1"/>
    <Reference Include="Dapper.StrongName, Version=1.60.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e3e8412083d25dd3">
        <ReferencePath>$(PkgDapper_StrongName)\Dapper.StrongName.dll</ReferencePath>
        <HintPath>$(PkgDapper_StrongName)\Dapper.StrongName.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>

The second mod has the same thing with version 2.0+.
Although both assemblies are present in the output dirs, and that linking works correctly in the editor, at runtime it's still only version 2.0 that's loaded for both mods (logging typeof(typeof(DapperV*::Dapper.SqlMapper).Assembly.GetName().FullName)).

Are you targeting .NET Framework 4.x - or .NET Core (or later, including .NET 5/6/7/8+)?

@Dai The game mod template makes us target .NET 4.7.2. I guess we shouldn't change that?

.NET Framework 4.x can use <bindingRedirect>, .NET Core-and-later has an alternative strategy. But anyway, you'll be fine with an "always use the latest version" policy provided that you not only strictly adhere to SemVer for your own packages but also that you never introduce any ABI-breaking-changes (such as removing any types or members - but those members can become NOOPs - the important thing is not to break the runtime on-load linking done by the CLR)

If I'm not wrong I can't use bindingRedirect either because that's a thing when you make in an app config when you control the resulting code base, not when you're a mod author, inside a project?

Better idea: because its your .exe you can just set a handler for AppDomain.AssemblyResolve and use that to redirect any attempts to load older versions of your library to the current latest version (so don't worry about app.config-based <bindingRedirect>).

Ah, no, sorry if that was ambiguous, It's not my exe. Actually it's Cities: Skylines II, so I only have the power of what a mod author can do inside their own DLL.

Then what's the harm in having two different versions of your utility assembly loaded into the same processs? Those mods/projects/etc will be consuming your assembly as a private dependency (right?).

I actually want that (rather than versioning my namespace and hoping the latest version is loaded). It just appears to be impossible to have both assemblies loaded at the same time (see my latest edit).

Seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451220/loading-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly

as a super hack, won't adding the version in the aseembly name work, i.e. AsemmblyV20, AsemmblyV16 work?

@Dai: yes, didn't help :/

@IvanPetrov Well wait a sec that's brilliant. I was so focused on the other problems and I didn't think about the fact that the NuGet name and assembly name aren't the same thing. So all mods could consume NuGet "UtilityLib" but use a different namespace and assembly according to the version they use. Makes sense?

@MorganTouvereyQuilling well, not sure about the NuGet packaging, but you want the assembly name to be different, the output dll too. How you package it from this point is kinda irrelevant, i.e. it won't have actual effect because we are resolving dlls and NuGet is not a concern at this point.

If you could force <bindingRedirect> we could have an easier solution, but since you are the library that mods consume you don't have the luxury of setting this.
One thing you can do is have truly different assemblies, not differentiated by version, but by name.
In other words, you have a naming scheme that incorporates the version in the assembly name:
AssemblyV10
AssemblyV12 

etc.
As such no conflicts will be possible and all assemblies will be resolved individually.
I am not sure, however, if NuGet allows to have a package have different versions based on different assembly names, not just different assembly versions.

I am gonna test the full solution with a local package and accept the answer if this works, but it seems promising, thanks!

All working wonderfully, both "versions" (UtilityV1 v1.0.0 and UtilityV2 v2.0.0) can even share the same namespace "Utility"!
Emulated with a local NuGet repo.
Not sure to understand your last sentence, but I'm pretty sure NuGet will accept anything as long as it's not an already-published version for the package name.

@MorganTouvereyQuilling Glad that it worked so far. You don't have many other options afaik.
I wasn't sure if MS NuGet doesn't enforce the same name of the assembly and allowed for just changes in version attributes (seemed improbable but still :))  - you won't use them anyway I think as distribution. Lastly, maybe use that approach for most releases, but not all, i.e. some hybrid approach where you don't mind conflicts between certain version which will work the same regardless of which assembly is loaded.

@MorganTouvereyQuilling: If this works, mark it as answer.

Sorry, completely forgot to accept it.
"> Lastly, maybe use that approach for most releases, but not all"
Absolutely, I intend to respect strict semver and change the assembly name when there is a breaking change in the ABI only. After all, reusing an already-loaded assembly is good for memory when they're compatible, it's just that I needed to handle breaking changes smoothly.

No problem. Yeah that would place nicely with enforcing semver as it should. Cheers.
